# How to query parent/child relation using matching _version?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having this join datatype

```
"Review_Sentence": {
  "type": "join",
  "relations": {
    "Review": "Sentence"
  }
},
```

If I have a review v1 like that

```
review_v1
  sentence1_v1
  sentence2_v1
  sentence3_v1
```

and later someone updates it and remove the last sentence

```
review_v2
  sentence1_v2
  sentence2_v2
```

then in Elastic searh I still have sentence3_v1 refering to the same review, so the query will return something like that

```
review_v2
  sentence1_v2
  sentence2_v2
  sentence3_v1
```

How can I make sure the child `_version` is the same as the parent `_version`. I tried to use an external `_version` but if elasticsearch is giving me the latest `_version` for `_id`, regardless if the parent/child `_version` are matching or not.

So far my workaround is to delete all children for that review and insert the new one, but this is introducing a latency that I would like to get rid of

Comment: Do you try to add the version to your request ? `GET <index>/_doc/<_id>?version=2`

Comment: No I can't, I don't know the version. I "just" want the last version that matches both parent and child